# Open, Save & Close file types Excel, Word, PowerPoint & Visio using only VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

Long-time user, first time asker.

In my current role I have a repetitive & laborious task which is effectively reviewing a number of documents on a SharePoint location (Version 2007). Once reviewed, the document is saved then SharePoint displays last saved time and this effectively validates the review for another month or so from a governance perspective.

The thing is, nothing much changes in these documents so most of the time it is literally a case of opening, saving and then closing all the documents.

I’m looking to automate this – I basically want some VBA code to open, save and close all the documents. The issue I am having is that there are 4 file types; Excel, Word, PowerPoint & Visio and from a number of google searches, I’m only able to work out how to automate the Excel files.

I have no issues with hardcoding the location of each document, my main issue is to get this Open, Save & Close automation working across all file types.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Your\Folder\Path" -Recurse -Include *.xlsx,*.pptx,*.vsdx,*.docx | foreach {$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date}
```

This peace of code will change 'LastWriteTime' attribute of files with xlsx, pptx, vsdx and docx extension, what actually save and close commands are doing.

Comment: Thanks for providing a reply. This doesn't work for Sharepoint, it doesn't recognise the address as a drive. Is there anyway to do it with VBA?

Comment: It works for me with net path. `\\someweb\somefolder`

Comment: If I drop the http: bit and run in Powershell, it doesn't fail but upon checking the documents, the time hasn't been updated. Am I inserting the net path in incorrect format?

Comment: You will need path to server folder. Sorry, I don't think that this will work is you use web address. Try to found direct server address. Sorry again.

Comment: I will try to find this. Thanks for your help so far with this. I did try on my local Windows shared drive and it worked like a dream so just need to get true server address. Thanks agains